# Appending uniform types vs separating

Tags: opengl, glsl

Suppose I have a structure for my point lights:

```cpp
uniform struct lights
{
    int size;          // overall number to iterate on
    vec3 position[20]; // 20 lights at most
    vec3 color[20];
    float radius[20];
    float intensity[20];
}
uni_point_lights;
```

and I am iterating through the properties `[0; uni_point_lights.size)` in a shader. Note that I am **not** using UBOs here, just usual uniforms. I also could've stored my properties like so:

```cpp
    vec4 position_and_radius[20];
    vec4 color_and_intensity[20];
```

e. g. I could append `vec3`s and `float`s into `vec4` and then just use `.xyz` and `.w` to access them separately.

Apparently, the first approach is easier in terms of understanding and code cleanliness. And the second approach, *imho*, could benefit due to some alignment-related limitations, but would require some additional work to separate meaningful information. Now, if I were talking about UBOs, the uniform block layout would answer my question (`vec3` would take the same space as `vec4` in `std140` for example). Unfortunately, I was not able to find any information regarding usual uniforms, everyone's talking about UBOs. Also note that I am using arrays here, not plain values.

Which approach is better and why?

Answer (score 1):

Implementations vary on how they go about dealing with non-block uniforms like this. There's no guidance on it because, well, non-block uniforms don't exactly have a track record of being high-performance anyway. They're bound to a single program object, so if you ever need to share this data, you're going to have to issue multiple `glProgramUniform*` calls for different programs. And interacting with non-block uniforms requires using a clunky API to change values.

The only advice that can be given is to arrange your data so that you have the fewest number of `glProgramUniform` calls, based on your frequency of changing those values. That is, if you set all of them frequently, then you should bundle the `float`s into array with the `vec3`s. But if you frequently only set the floats and only rarely set the others, they should be in separate arrays.

But ultimately, it probably won't matter. Not unless you're changing these things hundreds of times per frame. And if you are... you should be using UBOs. Or just a large SSBO that has multiple versions of the data structure for different objects, thus allowing you to draw multiple objects with a single draw call.

Basically, there's not much point in optimizing a scenario that's already not good for performance.

Comment: I calculate the lights **after** the whole scene is rendered into g-buffer (deferred rendering), so basically I update the whole thing (depending on what lights are in the scene) once a frame. I reckon it's already an improvement over having these and updating these for each object. Does this also fall into *scenario that's already not good for performance*?